# Existe APIs de interface gráfica para Grafos no android?

Tags: android, api, grafo

Procurei muito pela internet mas não achei nada correspondente em português e em inglês achei algumas coisas mas sem resolução sobre isso.
 Alguém tem algum conhecimento sobre a existência de uma API de interface gráfica para representar e manipular grafos (de nodos e arestas) no `Sistema Operacional Android`? 
Ou alguma sugestão de alternativa? (tal api deve ser open source).

Answer (score 4):

Para realizar a plotagem dos grafos no Android, você pode usar essas bibliotecas:

- [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) - Poderosa biblioteca para visualização de grafos e gráficos
- [AChartEngine](http://jaxenter.com/effort-free-graphs-on-android-with-achartengine-46199.html) - Biblioteca gráfica para aplicações Android
- [HoloGraphLibrary](https://github.com/Androguide/HoloGraphLibrary) - Biblioteca para plotagem de gráficos / grafos
- [EazeGraph](https://github.com/blackfizz/EazeGraph) - Biblioteca para plotagem de gráficos / grafos
- [AndroidCharts](https://github.com/dacer/AndroidCharts) - Biblioteca simples e fácil para manipular gráficos
- [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/docs/quickstart/) - Biblioteca para plotagem de gráficos
- [WilliamChart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart) - Biblioteca felxível para gráficos com suporte a animções
- [HelloCharts](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android) - Biblioteca de gráficos e grafos com suporte a redimensionamento, scroll e animações
- [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) - Biblioteca poderosa para visualização de grafos e gráficos com suporte a animações e várias outras funcionalidades.

Se você quiser manipular o grafo em si, ou seja, criar,remover e editar nós e arestas, você pode usar essas bibliotecas escritas em Java. Algumas delas já fornecem recursos para plotagem dos grafos.

- [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/)
- [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/)
- [G](http://geosoft.no/graphics/)
- [yWorks](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.html)
- [BFG](http://bfo.com/products/graph/docs/)
- [GEF](http://gef.tigris.org/)
- [gmgraphlib](http://code.google.com/p/gmgraphlib/)
- [Scene Graph](http://java.net/projects/scenegraph/)
- [JGraph](http://code.google.com/p/piccolo2d/)

**Fontes:**

- https://guides.codepath.com/android/Must-Have-Libraries#drawing
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162618/java-graph-library-for-dynamic-visualisation